# Keeping track of time in background to handle location updates

Tags: ios, swift, timer, location

I have two constraints in my app, one is user location and the other one is time. Following is the simple location implementation.

```
func determineMyCurrentLocation() {
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 20

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print("*******Location updated*******")
}
```

With this code, I expect to get triggered every time the user location changes by 20m (in background as well). However, I also need to track the time the user stays in a particular location. Since i need to track the background case, I cannot use timer.

I followed https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started to try background task but as stated in the article, the background time allowed that I got was around 3 min (which is variable). So i believe I cannot go with this.

How can I solve this?

EDIT: I also need to make an api call if the user stays in a location for X minutes. So for that case, it would not be feasible to wait for location updates and calculate the time differences. I could previously solve this by removing the distance filter and continuously checking the location and comparing the time and location. I guess continuous location tracking will get the app rejected, that's why I went for filter. But i am not sure if it will still get rejected or not since iOS will need to track the location for filter as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple `Date` objects to track the time spent between location updates even if your app is in the background. Simply declare a `Date` property for your class, update its value from `func locationManager(_:, didUpdateLocations:)` and compare that to the current time.

```
// Declare this in a scope that can be accessed from `didUpdateLocations` and where its value won't be released from memory
var lastUpdateTimestamp = Date()

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let now = Date()
    let timeSinceLastUpdate = now.timeIntervalSince(lastUpdateTimestamp)
    print("\(timeSinceLastUpdate) seconds passed since last location update")
    lastUpdateTimestamp = now
}
```

Response to the question edit: making an API call after X minutes have passed in the background without a location update is not possible, since there's no supported background mode for executing arbitrary functions at specific points in time. Getting rid of the distance filter as you explained in your edit could be a valid alternative, however if your app is only using location updates to be able to make the API calls and isn't actually doing anything with those locations, your app might indeed get rejected.

Comment: Though I have upvoted, this logic has a small flaw that you assume time taken by user to travel 20m (as thats the filter added) is so negligible that difference between two dates will give you the exact time user spent at specific location :) But in reality there will also be a time that we have to account for that user takes to walk 20 m :) But given a current iOS restrictions on background modes this is the best we can do I believe

Comment: @SandeepBhandari you are right, the "travel time" between location updates is neglected here. It could be measured by not setting a `distanceFilter` on the location manager, but manually filtering the location updates based on their distance from the last update in `didUpdateLocations`, since in that case it would be possible to track exactly when the user is moving.

Comment: I agree, but thats a trade off, we all are assuming (Believe me I am making same assumption that) OP is using startMonitoringLocation update API, but because of loads of restrictions on location updates especially in background mode if apple rejects the app and asks to use monitorSignificantLocationChanges only then the whole calculations might go for toss as in that case updates becomes fewer and fewer and occurs only for larger distances and in that case travel time cant be ignored :) But then probably I am overthinking n confusing OP :P

Comment: @sujal : If you have a very strong reason for monitoring user locations closely even when user puts app in background and if that literlly adds value to your user, you can get away with using no distance filter as mentioned by David in above comments. Because delegates gets triggered sooner and for a smaller displacements thats the best bet for u to update your server

Comment: @Sandeep Bhandari I have added an edit. If the time elapsed at a location crosses a threshold, i need to make api call. How can i track this time? And using the filter, how does iOS know that the distance criteria has been reached, does it still continuously keep track of location for that purpose?

Comment: @sujal : There are two APIs for tracking user location updates, one is StartMonitoringLocationUpdate which will track the location in realtime if no distance filter added and set the accuracy to highest level possible. But then apple  suggests that when used in background one should use MonitorSignificantLocationChanges API as name suggests it monitors significant displacement and will not be ver accurate. If you have real reason as to why u need real time monitoring of location and if u can convince apple review team u can use the first API. But thats a trade of because battery drainage

Comment: @SandeepBhandari The apple documentation does not mention how much is significant for MonitorSignificantLocationChanges. In some blogs, i came across 500m. What do you think?

Comment: @sujal : I have used it with 1km radius and that was enough for us. But it might not be enough for u, you might be needing a smaller radius, this is something you have to test it on your own buddy n get it clarified from apple

Answer (score 0):

When you receive a new location update, check the time difference from the previous update.. giving you the time that they were at the last location.

Depending on what you are doing with these location updates, this might just be pulling the latest update from some DB, or posting to an API.

An example..

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print("*******Location updated*******")
    let lastUpdateDate = // get the last datetime you received information

    let currentDate = Date()
    let minutesDifference = let componentsLeftTime = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute], from: lastUpdateDate, to: currentDate)
}
```

Comment: I would like to post to an API if the user has been in a location for a certain time eg. 10 min. So I cannot wait until next location update.